# How to parse slug from url using route of laravel to vue components

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to parse data to show product by using slug from laravel show route resource (get) to vue js components by using laravel api

example: https://shop.app/product/slug-name

i want to parse the slug-name into the vue components

```
export default {
    name: 'product',
    mounted() {
        // console.log('Component mounted.')
        this.fetchData()
    },
    data(){
        return{
            products: [],
            product: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                slug: '',
                description: '',
                image: '',
                created_at: '',
                updated_at: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData(){
            axios.get('/api/products')
            .then((res) => {
                this.products = res.data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

i expect the output from showing the slug name, not show all the products

Comment: Am not getting what you saying. you getting url from laravel api . or you are hitting that route and then get the current url in vuejs?

Comment: yes, i want to get current slug from opened page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Laravel Routes you can get your slug in to your Vue instance like

```
var slugName = '{{ $slug }}';
export default {
    name: 'product',
    methods: {
        fetchData(){
            //you can use slugNname here
            axios.get('/api/products/' + slugName)
        .then((res) => {
            this.products = res.data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

after that  you can use slugName in  your axios request

hope it helps

Comment: What if he is in the javascript file. like he said in vue component means vue file. how he can use the blade

Comment: yes it is in the javascript file, i have updated my answer please check it

Comment: first you would need to add the slugName to your data in your Vue instance, if your script is not in your blade you can either add the data to the window directly or I can recommend this library to manage data from the controllers to your views if you do this often. https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: @RicEz did you chcek my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get you current url by

```
let currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
```

and then you can use  lodash library its already included in laravel if you see you `boostrap.js` file

`let ar = _.split(currentUrl, '/');`

it will return your array. its just like `explode` in php. you can read about this [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#split)

and at last, get your product by

```
this.productName = _.last(ar);


`_.last` Its will just give you last element of your array which is your product. [here][2] is the documentation
```

you can make a method for this. like below

```
    getProductSlug(){

                    let currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
                    let ar = _.split(currentUrl, '/');
                    return _.last(ar);


                },
```

Comment: Its not the perfect way, but its a easy way to fix the problem. I do it to, thanks for tip.